# How to safely run user-provided Java code?

Tags: java

I'm developing a multiplayer game where the player has to provide code that will run inside a physics-based simulation.

The simulation runs in Java, and each player has to provide a class implementing a specific Interface (so not completely arbitrary code).

The player-provided code has to run inside the same main process, as it needs access to the physics simulation and any other solution won't allow to keep things fast enough.

Is there a way to implement this securely given these constraints?

Comment: **No**. There is no way to securely run user provided code. Java tried with Applets. It was called the "[sandbox](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/sandbox/)". It was not secure.

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'secure' though.  If you'll accept "can destroy the JVM environment but do no damage to the host system", then the usual OS process-isolation techniques apply. But no, you can't protect code in the JVM from code in the JVM.

Comment: You can add protection to some degree by using `SecurityManager` which has been deprecated though. See [here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/411) for some reasoning for the deprecation.

Comment: So how do the various “fiddle” web sites handle user-posted code that executes on the server?

Comment: I think they execute a separate sandboxed process, likely using Linux containers for further isolation